# Buefy field does not react on :message param change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, buefy

I have a Nuxt project with Buefy components. There is a form with some field component which should react on error according the message parameter for this component. But does not. I can see the correct value in debuger but component does not show the message. :message property should work like the in [first email example from documentation](https://buefy.org/documentation/field#api-view)

The code looks like:

```
<template #company>
    <h2 class="title">{{ $t('general.login.create_company') }}</h2>
    <b-field
        :type="loginErrors.company_name ? 'is-danger' : ''"
        :message="loginErrors.company_name ? loginErrors.company_name : ''"
    >
        <b-input
                v-model="companyName"
                name="company_name"
                type="text"
                autocomplete="off"
                :placeholder="$t('general.login.create_company')"
        ></b-input>
    </b-field>
    <div class="buttons is-centered">
        <b-button type="is-primary is-light" @click="createCompany">Save</b-button>
    </div>
</template>

...

data() {
    return {
        ...
        loginErrors: {},
        error: 'aaaaaa',
    };
},
...
async createCompany() {
    const result = await this.$api.users.createCompany({company_name: this.companyName});

    if( result.error ) {
        this.loginErrors.company_name = result.error;  // This does not work although the variable has correct value set
        this.error = result.error;  // This works fine
        return false;
    }
},
```

I use this pattern in other components and it works. I dont understand it. thaks for any help.

Comment: You should set the default "loginErrors.company_name" to null or an empty string. Then, in your HTML use ":message="loginErrors.company_name". This should allow your code to be reactive and show the proper message when "loginErrors.company_name" changes.

Comment: This does not work. It has to be something else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution in this case was to update Buefy version from 0.4.11 to 0.4.21. This fix the issue. Another thing is that is causes new issue with :type in combination with grouped param.

Answer (score 2):

> change detection of data objects in Vue is shallow (top level only)

In `vue.js`, Dynamically added property to an object is not reactive. Instead we can assign a whole object so that change detection happen.

For a better understanding please go through this official [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked) of Vue.

**Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      loginErrors: {}
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loginErrors = {
      company_name: 'some value'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ loginErrors.company_name ? 'is-danger' : 'no-danger' }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't really have to assign an initial empty string to `loginErrors.company_name`. But you have to assign to `loginErrors` (top level) when you add `company_name`, not to `loginErrors.company_name`. In other words, with initial `loginErrors: {}`, `this.loginErrors = { company_name: 'whatever' }` will work. A better wording for the reason would be: *"change detection of data objects in Vue is shallow (top level only)"*.

Comment: It seems it is not true. The problem is in this line 
`:message="loginErrors.company_name ? loginErrors.company_name : ''"` Everything else works well, so it means it is reactive.

Comment: @tao Thanks for pointing that out. I modified the answer.

Comment: @Čamo, the problem is with this line in your code: `this.loginErrors.company_name = result.error;`. Change it to `this.loginErrors = { company_name: result.error };`

Comment: The problem is in this line: :message="loginErrors.company_name ? loginErrors.company_name : ''" everything else including class is-danger works well.

Comment: @Čamo As per your code, you said : `this.loginErrors.company_name = result.error;  // This does not work although the variable has correct value set`. Hence, we added an explanation why this is not working and how it will work. So please have a look. It will definately help you in resolving the issue you are facing.

Comment: Sorry but the solution in my case was to update the Buefy version and it works. Antoher thing is that it reases new issue but it is not so critical.

Comment: @Čamo Glad that issue got resolved. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Vue components react to object property changed in a direct way, you could try `this.$set(this.loginErrors, 'company_name', result.error);` instead of `this.loginErrors.company_name = result.error;`

***FYI:*** https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html?redirect=true#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: It does not make sense. I have another usecase which works and it looks like:
`this.formErrors = result.inputs;`

Comment: The problem is in this line: `:message="loginErrors.company_name ? loginErrors.company_name : ''"` everything else including class is-danger works well.

Comment: They are different cases. When assigning `this.formErrors = result.inputs;`, you change the value of a variable of data and Vue can detect it. But when it comes to `this.loginErrors.company_name = result.error;` ,Vue cannot detect the change explicitly due to it's a modification inside an object. So that's why I think invoking `this.$set` may solve your problem

Comment: Sorry but the solution in my case was to update the Buefy version and it works. Antoher thing is that it reases new issue with :type but it is not so critical.